# Check if 2 mesh surfaces are equal

Tags: cgal

I am trying to check if 2 mesh surfaces are equal but my method is slow.

1. Equal volumes.
2. Calculate the difference : mesh 1 - mesh 2
3. Check that the mesh calculated in point 2 has a null volume and a null surface.

Is there a faster method?

2 mesh surfaces are if they have same topology and same geometry.

Comment: Are the equal meshes supposed to have exactly the same number of elements?

Comment: In some cases yes, in others cases no. The method must give result in all cases.

Comment: You need to precise what you mean by "2 mesh are equal". A mesh has a topology (cells and adjacency relations) and a geometry. Do you want the same topology ? The same geometry ? Both ? Testing the same topology is done using isomorphism. The algorithm is fast (linear in number of halfedges). You can also test geometry during this algorithm; thus testing both topology and geometry.

Comment: @gdamiand Can you give me an example code to use isomorphism to check the equality of 2 meshed surfaces.